# How to create edges propagating from a single node with respect to distance in a Graph

Tags: java, arraylist, nodes, graph-theory

I have a graph where I need to create directed edges from a single node out to all the nodes that are within a certain distance from that node, directed from the initial node towards the nodes that are within distance. Then it creates edges from the nodes that were in distance from the initial node to the nodes that are within distance of those nodes and it keeps going until every node has at least one edge.

I'm having problem conceptualizing this in code and putting it into practice. I have this following code currently which kind of works but not well enough, as sometimes the nodes further away from the initial node don't get edges:

```
//create patient zero
    graphVer.get(0).getValue().setInfected(true);
    graphVer.get(0).getValue().setRecentlyInfected(true);
    graphVer.get(0).getValue().setLevel(0);
    for(int i = 0; i < graphVer.size();i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < graphVer.size();j++) {
            //checks each vertex against every other vertex, and if their distance is within limits and they aren't equal to each other, then create an edge between them
            if(distance(graphVer.get(i).getValue().getX(), graphVer.get(i).getValue().getY(),graphVer.get(j).getValue().getX(),graphVer.get(j).getValue().getY()) < dis.getRange()) {
                if(i != j) {
                    //makes sure that there is only one edge between two nodes and directs it based on where patient zero is
                    if(graphVer.get(i).getValue().getLevel() <= i && graphVer.get(j).getValue().getLevel() > graphVer.get(i).getValue().getLevel()) {
                        graphEdge.add(new Edge<>(0,graphVer.get(i),graphVer.get(j)));
                        graphVer.get(j).getValue().setLevel(i+1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I haven't included the code of the vertex creation, which just randomly creates vertexes within a square bound making sure none overlap. graphVer is an arraylist of all the vertices in the graph, and graphEdge is an arraylist of all edges in the graph.

What's a better way of doing this so it works properly every time?

Comment: Your problem spec has problems. What should the output graph look like?  Can it have cycles?  Should it be a tree rooted at the start vertex?  Finally, you imply that every node will eventually be connected in the graph in all cases. That's not true. If a node is more than the "certain distance" from all other nodes, how can it ever be connected?

Answer (score 0):

Your wording is a bit confusing, aren't you only trying to reach nodes that are within a set distance from the original node? If that's the case, then "sometimes the nodes further away from the initial node don't get edges" would be what you want to happen.

Comment: I'm initially looking at the first node, then I'm looking at all the nodes that are close to the first node and looking for nodes that are close to those nodes, not the initial nodes, and that keeps going until all nodes have been visited

Answer (score 0):

I pointed out the shortcomings in your problem spec in the comments.

What I *think* you want, conceptually, is to start with the graph G of *all* edges (v,w) where dist(v,w) <= DIST. This will contain many cycles.  Within this graph, you want to find a tree T discovered by searching breadth first from the start vertex.

To achieve this, you don't need to construct G. As you've inferred, you can iterate over all vertex pairs and test them with dist(v,w) <= DIST to discover the edges in G as they're needed.

BFS uses a queue. You'd end up with this algorithm:

```
Let x be the start vertex
Let N be a set initially containing all vertices (not yet infected)
Let Q be a queue for vertices
Let T be the initially empty set of tree edges
Add x to Q and remove it from N // Infect x.
while Q is not empty
  Pop vertex v from the head of Q
  for each vertex w in N // Iterate through all non-infected vertices
    if dist(v, w) < DIST
      Add edge v->w to T // w is now infected
      add w to the tail of Q
      remove w from N
return T
```

This translates almost line-for-line to Java.

Note that the output must be a tree because each vertex w can be removed from N only once. Consequently there can only be one edge of the form v->w in T. That means every vertex has at most one parent, which is the definition of a directed tree.

As I said in comments, there's no guarantee this will include all vertices in the tree if gaps between them are too large.

Just for fun, here's a sample output for randomly located vertices. The start vertex is the double-sized one toward the upper left corner.

[image]

Note the vertices not included because they're too far from any source of infection. This is correct.